# Probability with Dices and Tiles

Tags: probability

Ten tiles numbered 1 through 10 are turned face down. One tile is turned up at random, and a die is rolled. What is the probability that the product of the numbers on the tile and the die will be a square?

I'm thinking 1/10, but I'm not sure, since I don't have so much experience.

Comment: Give us more detail.  How did you get the number $\frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: Since a die has 6 sides and there are 10 tiles, I thought 10. I'm pretty sure its wrong. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Another question, what do they mean by "square" in this problem?

Comment: It most likely means a perfect square (the square of an integer).

Comment: Also, the plural of *die* is *dice*, not *dices*.

Comment: I think you'll need to go back to the very basic concepts regarding probability.  Review the definitions of random experiment, outcome, sample space, event, and probability.

Comment: I think you also have some confusion between English and mathematical terms.  (In English, the tile is a square and the die is a cube, but in mathematical terms, the square of $x$ is $x^2$ and the cube of $x$ is $x^3$.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case where you just have to count up all the outcomes, not much calculating.

What are the products that are squares?  1, 4(3 ways), 9(2 ways), 16(2 ways), 25, 36.

And then calculate how many total outcomes there are.

EDIT:  Favorable outcomes

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\text{Tile}& \text{Die}&\text{Product} \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 4& 4  \\ \hline
2& 2 & 4 \\ \hline
4 & 1 & 4 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 9 \\ \hline
9 & 1 & 9 \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 16 \\ \hline
8 & 2 & 16 \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 25 \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 36 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

When calculating probabilities, you first need to find the sample space.  In your case, the sample space is {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,1),...,(2,6),...,(10,1),...,(10,6)} (where I've chosen the first element in each ordered pair to be the outcome of the numbered tile, and the second element to be the outcome of the die).  There are 10$\times$6=60 elements in the sample space.

In this case, the elements of the sample space are equally likely, so that simplifies things a lot.  As turkeyhundt has pointed out, the event you are interested in has 10 elements.  Now use the definition of probability for equally likely outcomes to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1/6

10 good outcomes where the product is a perfect square
1=  1,1
4=  1,4 2,2 4,1
9=  3,3 9,1
16= 4,4 8,2
25= 5,5
36= 6,6

60 possible results, 10 tiles * 6 dice throws

10/60 = 1/6

Comment: Your answer is correct, but perhaps it would have been better if you had let the OP (original poster) find out the final answer on his/her own, since it is quite an easy and important final step.